# Why do i get an empty output for my code in C++ ?? Where am I mistaken?

Tags: c++, max

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int howMany, num[howMany], max; //defining variables
    
    cout<<"How many numbers do you want to add? (Enter your number and press enter): ";
    cin>>howMany;
    
    for(int i=1;i<=howMany;++i){
        cout<<"Enter you number: ";
        cin>>num[i-1];
    }
    
    max=num[0];
    for (int element:num){
        max=(max>=element)?max:element;
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

well i actually wanted to find the largest number out of a given set of numbers....
i wanted to take an input from a user on how many numbers he wants to add. then i take all those numbers, for that i made a loop. and then i compare each element of that array of numbers with the previous one to find the largest number. i compiled my code, received no errors....and then when i run it i get an empty output. like this:[my output img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x87As.png). please help me out!!!

Comment: Fyi, if the purpose is to find the max of user input and report it (which you're currently not doing), you don't need an array for this anyway. You need two `int` values: the current max, and the value-just-read. the former is updated when the latter exceeds it.

Comment: `num[howMany]` is a mistake, and is not C++ because `howMany` is not a `const` or `constexpr`.  You should enable your compiler warnings, then fix those warnings.

Comment: `int howMany, num[howMany], max;` does not set up `num` as an array that magically resizes whenever `howMany` is changed.     It is actually not valid C++.

Comment: @Peter but it works, somehow 

Comment: @AbdulqadarManasawala It works doesn't mean that it is correct. One answer already explains this.

Comment: @AbdulqadarManasawala   Unfortunately, some C++ compilers support variable-length arrays (VLA for short, a feature from the 1999 C standard, that is *not* part of standard C++) as a *non-standard* extension.    Even with those compilers, however, you are not using VLAs correctly - your code might compile, but you are setting up an array with a size that is an indeterminate junk value (since accessing the value of `howMany` before it is initialised gives undefined behaviour - in either C or C++).

Answer (score 4):

You declared a variable length array `num`

```
 int howMany, num[howMany], max; //defining variables
```

Variable length arrays is not a standard C++ feature.

Moreover in the declaration you are using an uninitialized variable `howMany`. So the program has undefined behavior.

Instead of the variable length array you could use the standard container `std::vector<int>`.

Pay attention to that there is standard algorithm `std::max_element` in C++ that allows to find the maximum element in an array.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    size_t howMany = 0;

    std::cout << "How many numbers do you want to add? (Enter your number and press enter): ";

    std::cin >> howMany;

    std::vector<int> num( howMany );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < howMany; ++i ) 
    {
        std::cout << "Enter you number: ";
        std::cin >> num[i];
    }

    auto it = std::max_element( std::begin( num ), std::end( num ) );

    if (it != std::end( num ))
    {
        std::cout << "The maximum value is " << *it << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are **2 problems** with your program.

##### Mistake 1

You didn't initialize the variable `howMany`. This means it holds an **indeterminate value**. And using this uninitialized variable as you did when you wrote `num[howMany]` leads to **undefined behavior**.

> Undefined behavior means anything can happen *including but not limited to* program being successfully compiled and giving your expected output. But **don't rely** on the output of a program that has undefined behavior.

For more reading(technical definition of) on undefined behavior you can refer to [undefined behavior's documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) which mentions:

> there are *no restrictions* on the behavior of the program.

This is why it is advised that

> Always initialize built in types in local/block scope.

##### Mistake 2

In Standard C++ the size of an array must be a [**compile-time constant**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression). So for example, consider the following examples:

```
int n = 10;
int arr[n]; //INCORRECT
```

The correct way to write the above would be:

```
const int n = 10;
int arr[n]; //CORRECT
```

Similarly, in your code,

```
int howMany, num[howMany]; //INCORRECT because howMany is not a constant expression
```

##### Solution

You can solve this by using a [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main(){
    int howMany = 0, max = 0; //defining variables
    
    std::cout<<"How many numbers do you want to add? (Enter your number and press enter): ";
    std::cin>>howMany;
    
    //create a vector of size howMany
    std::vector<int> num(howMany);
    
    //iterate and take input from user
    for(int &elem: num){
        std::cout<<"Enter you number: ";
        std::cin>>elem;
    }
    
    max=num.at(0);
    for (int i = 1; i < num.size(); ++i){
        if(num[i] > max)
        {
            max = num[i];
        }
    }
    std::cout<<"biggest number is: "<<max;
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: i, without changing the data type of the array, could get the required output  and even i did not find adding the vector library necessary for my code, even without that am good to go!!!

Comment: @AbdulqadarManasawala Just because you're getting your expected output doesn't make your program correct. Read in my answer, i have written that **Don't rely on the output of a program that has undefined behavior**.

Comment: @AbdulqadarManasawala If you want to learn C++ I recommend adding a few compiler options: `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic` and to catch a lot of the UB situations in runtime you could also add `-g -fsanitize=address,undefined`.